# How to draw cube in a cube?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'd like to draw a cube in a cube using TikZ as the above. I know how to draw a 3-dimensional vector space, with a line. But, I don't know how to draw a cube in TikZ. What code should I use for it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikz}
\draw %?
\end{tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Btw, some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Andrew What does "gui" mean?

Comment: @buzzee - Graphical User Interface, in this case your LaTeX editor.

Comment: @buzzee  By the gui I mean the (graphical user) web interface that you used to write your question. One of the editor buttons at the top of the screen looks like `{}` this is can be used to highlight blocks of code.

Comment: Do you need a perspective projection like in your example images (note how no two lines are actually parallel) or would an isometric projection (where all parallel lines in 3D space would also be parallel in the 2D image) be acceptable. The latter is a lot easier to do with TikZ.

Comment: @wrtlprnft. No, mine has something similar to an isometric projection, so I was expecting an isometric projection or an oblique projection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). The "viewing angle" that tikz uses is a little different to that in the question.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[inside/.style={fill=cyan!80,draw opacity=0.5,thick},
                        outside/.style={thick},
                        every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
        \draw[inside](-1,-1,-1)--(-1,1,-1)--(-1,1,1)--(-1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        \draw[inside](-1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        \draw[inside](-1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,-1)--(1,1,-1)--(-1,1,-1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        \draw[inside](1,1,1)--(1,-1,1)--(1,-1,-1)--(1,1,-1)--(1,1,1);
        \draw[inside](1,1,1)--(-1,1,1)--(-1,1,-1)--(1,1,-1)--(1,1,1);
        \draw[inside](1,1,1)--(-1,1,1)--(-1,-1,1)--(1,-1,1)--(1,1,1);
        %% inside frame - this shouldn't be necessary...
        \draw[gray](-1,-1,-1)--(-1,1,-1)--(-1,1,1)--(-1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        \draw[gray](-1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        \draw[gray](-1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,-1)--(1,1,-1)--(-1,1,-1)--(-1,-1,-1);
        %%
        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(-2,2,-2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(-2,2,-2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(2,-2,2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(2,2,2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(2,2,2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(2,-2,2)--(2,2,2);
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,1} {
             \draw(\x,-2,2)node[below]{$\x$}--++(0,0,-0.2);
             \draw(-2,\x,2)node[left]{$\x$}--++(0.2,0,0);
             \draw(2,-2,\x)node[right]{$\x$}--++(-0.2,0,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```